# Find a vector satisfying $\|x\|_2=1$ such that $\|Ax\|_2=\|A\|_2$

Tags: matrices, normed-spaces

Find a vector satisfying $\|x\|_2=1$ such that $\|Ax\|_2=\|A\|_2$

where $A=\begin{bmatrix}
-1 & 1\\ 
 2& 2
\end{bmatrix}$

I know that $\|A\|_2=\sqrt{\lambda_{\max}AA^T}$. But I'm not sure how to use this concept here.
Can some helps me here?

Comment: Are you sure about that definition? That gives a matrix when the matrix norm is a number.

Comment: Well, the definition I'm used to is $$\|A\|_2=\sup_{\|x\|_2=1}\|Ax\|_2$$So, you just need to find the $x$ with norm $1$ which maximizes $\|Ax\|_2$.

Comment: A unit vector in $\mathbb{R}^2$ can be written $x = (\cos(t),\sin(t))$. You can use that to evaluate $\|Ax\|_2$ ass function of $t$ and then maximize it.

Comment: @NinadMunshi:  Perhaps the OP means the largest eigenvalue $\lambda_{max}$ of the semi-definite matrix $AA^T$, so one takes the square root of a scalar.

Comment: @hardmath yeah, that's it. It is equivalent to the usual definition of norm 2, but he have written with a weird notation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint: let $x = (\cos t, \sin t)$, then $\lVert Ax \rVert_2^2 = 5 + 3\sin(2t)$.

Remember that the operator norm is defined by $\lVert A \rVert = \sup_{\lVert x \rVert = 1} \lVert Ax \rVert$.